# SharePoint 2010: Quick Launch Navigation Levels

Tags: sharepoint-2010, navigation, quicklaunch

Can someone tell me how to configure the OOTB AspMenu control to achieve the following:

- The quick launch should only show 1 level of static items
- **Except** for headings, these are meaningless on their own so the pages/links beneath them should also be displayed
- The menu should not display an dynamic flyouts

Essentially, the navigation menu should appear as follows (assume that the subsites both have child sites and/or pages but which should be hidden):

```
Starting Node 
- Subsite1
- Subsite2
- Page1  
- Heading
  - Page2
  - Page3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a way to achieve this functionality using the properties of the AspMenu control, so instead I just explicitly removed and subsite's child items in the **MenuItemDataBoundEvent** as follows:

```
protected void CurrentNavigationMenu_MenuItemDataBound(object sender, MenuEventArgs e)
{
    // Hide the contents of subsites (only level-1 links beneath headings are displayed).
    if (e.Item.Parent != null && e.Item.Parent.Selectable)
        e.Item.Parent.ChildItems.Remove(e.Item);
}
```